# cefsharp ExecuteScriptAsync(json) uri too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, winforms, cefsharp

I am using cefSharp in my winForm application.
I want to pass a long json from my winform to the html page displayed by the cefSharp.
I tried to write the following:

```
Private WithEvents m_chromeBrowser As ChromiumWebBrowser
...
CefSharp.Cef.Initialize()
page = New Uri("www...")
m_chromeBrowser = New ChromiumWebBrowser(page.ToString)
Panel.Controls.Add(m_chromeBrowser)
...
Dim json as String = "[{code:1,name:a,val:0},{...}....]"
m_chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("functionName('" & json & "');")
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Request-URI Too Long

Do you have any idea how to pass long json from winform to browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would be better off exposing a .Net class to JavaScript by registering an AsyncJSObject, execute the class method from JavaScript and parse the return result.

Something like this:

```
public class CallbackObjectForJs {
    public string getJson() {
        return myJsonString;
    }
}
```

... then register the class:

```
_webBrowser.RegisterAsyncJsObject(
    "Browser", 
    new CallbackObjectForJs(), 
    BindingOptions.DefaultBinder);
```

... and finally call the method from Javascript and use a promise to get the result:

```
Browser.getJson().then((result) => {
    var myJsonString = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(myJsonString);
});
```

You can read more about it here: 
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

Hope it helps!